# Finding the downloaded filetype from HTTP message

Tags: java, http, security, zap

I am trying to build a basic downloaded file scanning extension for the popular open source security application ZAP. using the built in sniffer, I can access the HTTP response messages. I am unable to determine the filetype of the file being downloaded. Although the [Mozilla blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) regarding HTTP talks about using the MIME Type in the 'Content-Type' header to determine the file type, I find that none of the response messages that I get have anything other than `application/json` or `text/html` or `application/octet-stream`. How do I determine if the corresponding HTTP response body contains any particular file type? . I am thus stuck at a dead end!

I am a beginner in this field and there might be something that I am over looking. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of things are you downloading?

Comment: Images (Jpeg/Png), Zip files, PDF and Executable files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

Taken from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616 under "14.17 Content-Type"

They give this as an example:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-4
```

This HTTP request or response contains text in the form of a body of HTML.

If you do not trust this header (which most of the time you can), the next step would be analyzing the file contents. For example, if the file contains opening and closing HTML tags, then there is a good chance that the file is an HTML file. If the file begins with a `[` or `{` and ends with a `]` or `}` then there is a good chance that it is a JSON file. An actual analysis would and should be much more detailed, of course.